# jQuery .each inside function

Tags: jquery

I dont know why .each() not working here in my code

```
function showhide(id){
    $('#mydiv'+id).each(function(){
    if(this).is(":visible") ) {
      $(this).css('display','none'); 
    }else {     
      $(this).css('display','block');       
        }
    });
}

<span id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
blah blah blah
</span>

<a href="#" onclick="showhide($id);return false;" />show/hide</a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? And why are you looping in the first place? There's only one span tag. Why are you using an ID ? ID's are supposed to be unique, why would you have an element with more than one ID?

Comment: i have 2 sections in the same page and they share the same post id and i want to show/hide them in the same time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an id selector - id's should be unique within the page, so calling .each with an id selector makes no sense.

Instead assign a class to each of the elements involved and use

```
$('.mydivclass').each( ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your 3rd line has some syntax problems. Here it is cleaned up;

```
...
if ( $(this).is(":visible") ) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have stated, ID's are supposed to be unique, so it doesn't make much sense to iterate over multiple elements with the same ID, use a class instead.

Also, a better way to structure your JavaScript is to attache your event handlers (onclick in your case) in one place and not inline in your html, this makes for cleaner code and is also easier to maintain.

Instead of accessing the css property directly i.e `$('yourelement').css('display', 'none')` 
you can do `$('yourelement').hide()` or `$('yourelement').show()`;

So your JS now looks like the one below.

```
$(function(){
   var my_divs = $('.mydiv'); 
   $('#show_hide').click(function(){
       my_divs.each(function(){
           var $this = $(this); 
           if( $this.is(':visible') )
               $this.hide(); 
           else 
               $this.show(); 
       }); 
   }); 
});
```

In your HTML you now have.

```
<span class="mydiv">
    blah blah blah
</span>

<a id="show_hide" href="#" />show/hide</a>
```

in your css file

```
.mydiv{
  display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showhide(id){
    $('#mydiv'+id).each(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible") ) {
      $(this).css('display','none'); 
    }else {     
      $(this).css('display','block');       
        }
    });
}
```

This should be the final product

Comment: This solution does not solve the problem in any way. Refer to the accepted answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function showhide(id){
    $('#'+id).each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(":visible") ) {
            $this.css('display','none'); 
        }else {     
            $this.css('display','block');       
        }
    });
}
```

Or

```
function showhide(id){
    $('#'+id).each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(":visible") ) {
            $this.hide(); 
        }else {     
            $this.show();       
        }
    });
}

<span id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
blah blah blah
</span>

<a href="#" onclick="showhide("mydiv");return false;" />show/hide</a>
```

Comment: This solution does not solve the problem in any way. Refer to the accepted answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

While the underlying problem has been solved in the accepted answer, you might drastically simplify your code:

```
function showhide(classname){
  $('.' + classname).toggle();
}
```

The explicit iteration with `.each` is unnecessary, since most jQuery methods automatically iterate over all matched elements in the jQuery object. Moreover, the showing and hiding can be done with `.toggle`.